# Javascript not executing completely

Tags: javascript

These are the javascript functions that i have written

```
function showAllVesselsProductsParent()
{   confirm ("test1");
    showAllVessels('regular', 'vesselsExpandDown', 'vesselsExpandUp');
    confirm ("test2");
    showAllVessels('composite', 'compVesselsExpandDown', 'compVesselsExpandUp');
}

function showAllVessels(type, div1, div2){
    confirm(type+"===="+div1+"======="+div2);
    var tableId = "";
    if(type=="regular"){
        confirm ("First Time");
        tableId = "vesselsTable";
    }else if(type=="composite") {
        confirm ("Second Time");
        tableId = "compositeVesselsTable";
    }
    var vesselsTable = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var vesselCount = vesselsTable.rows.length-1;

    if(vesselCount>0){
        var vesselId = "";
        if(type=='regular'){
            confirm ("regular");
            vesselId = "vessel";
        }else{
            confirm ("compVessel");
            vesselId = "compVessel";
        }
        for(i=0;i<vesselCount;i++){
            if(type=='regular'){
            var isDeleted = document.getElementById("addJobVessels["+i+"].isDeleted").value;
            if(isDeleted != "true"){
                confirm ("1");
                    document.getElementById(vesselId+i).style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById(vesselId+i).style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById(div1).style.visibility = "visible"; 
                    document.getElementById(div2).style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
            }else{
                confirm ("2");
                document.getElementById(vesselId+i).style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById(vesselId+i).style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById(div1).style.visibility = "visible"; 
                document.getElementById(div2).style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Code Executes with The following messages order:-

```
output:-

test1
regular====vesselsExpandDown====vesselsExpandUp
First Time
regular
1
test2
composite====vesselsExpandDown====vesselsExpandUp
```

However it dosent execute after this  , what could be the problem..

..................................................................................................................................................

Comment: ya why dosent it execute completely ,confirm  just gives an popup i have put it for testing perpose

Comment: `#compositeVesselsTable` probubly has no rows: `if (vesselsTable.rows.length - 1 > 0) {…}` Also you probably misspelled "composite". Also your code has 7 `=` but your output only has 4 and so your not really giving us the true code. Finally, it would be easier to read if your coding style was consistent. Pick one style and stick with it. And use a style that includes spaces cause tryingtoreadcodewithnospaces sucks!

Comment: Perhaps it does not find the document element  'compositeVesselsTable' and runs into error. In this case it could be, that the "confirm" function isnt finished yet when you run into nullpointer with this code "vesselsTable.rows.length-1;" Can you post your DOM elements?

Comment: As it stands, it is not possible to replicate and therefore diagnose this issue. As per other comments, it is clear that the output provide is not being produced by the same code in the question. You need to edit your question and provide the correct code, also please clarify the exact piece of code that is not running as expected. It is unclear if you mean "Second Time" or the vesselCode code block. I suggest you use `console.log("");` instead of prompt, and provide us with the full console output

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that the condition:

```
if(vesselCount>0){
...
}
```

is true. Perhaps add an else statement clarify the execution:

```
else {
confirm("vesselCount==0 in " + tableId );
}
```

Comment: That does not explain why "Second Time" is not reached

Comment: That's right, that does not explain it...  But I'm agree with other answers: You must add code to assert the execution flow. It appears that's all ok, but the triple equals, and the final "else" in the "if(type==" can be help us to clarify this strange case...  (Sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0):

First please pick one coding style and stick with it. Switching styles in the middle is very difficult to read. Also most find it difficult to read code that does not have spaces. Itisliketryingtoreadthissentence. For example:

```
if(foo=="bar"){
```

is easier to read like this:

```
if (foo === "bar") {
```

(I use triple `===` because it does what you want much more often then `==`. See [Douglas Crockford's Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)).

Check out [the w3c's JavaScript best practices](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_mixing_with_other_technologies) for a good place to start.

Next your first if statement says

```
IF the first argument (called "type") MATCHES the string "regular"
THEN output "First Time".
HOWEVER, if the previous condition is NOT met AND the "type" MATCHES the string "composite"
THEN output "Second Time".
OTHERWISE if neither of those two thing happen above
THEN no nothing and confuse the programmer further.
```

Since "Second Time" never printed it is safe to assume that the word **composite** was *mispelled*.

This is further corroborated in the fact that the output in the code:

```
confirm(type+"===="+div1+"======="+div2);
```

Has **7 `=`** signs but the output:

```
composite====vesselsExpandDown====vesselsExpandUp
```

Only has **4 `=`** signs and ∴ the code provided is *not* the code that produced the output.

Comment: So what exactly are you saying is the solution? It seems everyone is just guessing at answers. We can see how the method in called and "composite" is not mispelled, I hear what you are saying about the equals signs. I think we should hold off answering until the OP provides some clarification

Answer (score -1):

Switch this code:

```
if(type=="regular"){
    confirm ("First Time");
    tableId = "vesselsTable";
}else if(type=="composite") {
    confirm ("Second Time");
    tableId = "compositeVesselsTable";
}
```

To:

```
switch(type){
    case "regular":
        confirm ("First Time");
        tableId = "vesselsTable";
         break;
    case "composite":
        confirm ("Second Time");
        tableId = "compositeVesselsTable";
        break;
    default:
        alert('Invalid type ' + type);
        return false;
}
```

to have that part clean, and you are on the save side with the type.

Then check if this Variable

```
var vesselsTable = document.getElementById(tableId);
```

has the expected type and the expected attribute rows

Comment: That does not explain why "Second Time" is not reached, you are just giving OP code review advise, which is not the question

Comment: The Code does not run, because there is no table with id compositeVesselsTable. 

See this example without any html:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqmrXN

Beside: Without html you can only guess, what is going wrong.